# Оптимизация под ios 8

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Скажите, как оптимизировать приложение под ios 8 (просто включить на новом хкоде и исправить возникшие ошибки)? Приложение висит на проверке у эпла, и на новой прошивке у меня на телефоне оно полноценно работает!

Comment: Вот так вопрос, просто идеальный!!!

Answer (score 1):

Даже если Вы оптимизируете Ваше приложение под iOS8, то можете получить реджект за то, что не оптимизировали его же под iOS8 + iPhone6 Plus. По закону Эпполы, Вы должны иметь все последние дивайсы, и последние беты, и, естественно, последний xCode. Приоритет стоит на новых дивайсах и на новом ПО. Не так страшно то, что Ваше приложение крашется, под ios6 + iPhone3, как страшно, что крашется под iPhone 6 Plus +iOs8. И не важно, что ваше приложение работает идеально в симуляторе, как показала [моя недавнишняя практика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/363130/xcode-coredata-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ios8), код не всегда успешно работает на девайсе, даже если успешно работает на симуляторе.