# CoreData Не работает на iOS8

Tags: xcode, orm, ios, coredata, база-данных

Привет коллеги. Вот я и столкнулся с проблемкой, которая заставляет меня переехать с CoreData на что-то более умное и надежное.
Вопрос такой: как мне быстро мигрировать на другую ОРМку, более надежную, и сильно не потеть?
Если что, проект еще только готовится к релизу, и можно все переделать :) И вообще, стоит ли дергаться, ведь, может быть, Apple пофиксит багу где-нибудь к iOS9?

p.s. Есть желание форкнуть [iActiveRecords](https://github.com/AlexDenisov/iActiveRecord)  :) интересно знать, вопрос с многопоточностью решался или нет у @AlexDenisov.

Сама проблема, с которой я встретился и провел доскональный ресерч, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967700/magicalrecord-crashed-on-ios8).

```
2014-09-26 14:41:37.418 TestCoreData[412:61215] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '"CDSession" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magical Record не очень-то боеспособна, я написал свою либу для работы с CoreData, отлично справляется, единственное, NSManagedObjects нельзя генерить в swift, иначе все очень плохо. В целом никаких проблем с CoreData в iOS 8 я не нашел. Если интересно, могу кинуть свою либу, для fetches я взял за основу Magical Record, остальное переписал, потому что проблемы с ней были еще на iOS 5, тогда-то я и не выдержал.

В принципе никуда переходить с Core Data не советую, а в iOS 8 появились довольно интересные фичи, например, background fetching.

Посмотрел твой тестовый проект, нашел, в чем проблема:

**Класс CDSession уже есть в системном фреймворке CoreDuet**, посмотри, он на это и ругается! 
У меня уже было один раз так, у меня был класс EKEvent в CoreData - в такой же ситуации оказался. **Решается простым переименованием класса**, я переименовал сейчас твой класс в CDMSession, и все стало норм на девайсе.

Comment: @iFreeman, можешь глянуть мой проект: http://cl.ly/2b0R2I3W3Y1P на устройстве падает... не могу найти причину, либо я нуб, что-то не так делаю... Посмотри именно работу на ios8 на девайсе.

Comment: @Bimawa смотрю, отпишу минут через 10.
___

@Bimawa не падает, добавил NSLog(@"results = %@", result); после фетча, после нескольких запусков вижу в логах созданные объекты. xCode 6, запускаю на симуляторе iPhone 6.

Comment: И что ж это может быть? А проверил точно не в симуляторе, а на девайсе? Я стабильно падаю: 2014-09-26 14:41:37.418 TestCoreData[412:61215] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '"CDSession" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.'
____

А на симуляторе-то и у меня работает )

Comment: @Bimawa, понял, в чем ошибка!
____

@Bimawa, посмотри, обновил ответ!

Comment: Ты спас мне жизнь! Поставь свой комент в ответ, пожалуйста.